# numpy equivalent of pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, subset

I have the following numpy array:

```
x = np.arange(9.).reshape(3, 3)
```

thus:

```
>>>> x
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 6.,  7.,  8.]])
```

I want to select all rows where the third column is bigger than 2.

In pandas, I would do:

```
import pandas as pd
d = DataFrame(x)

>>>> d[d.iloc[:,2]>2]
```

and the output would be:

```
   0  1  2
1  3  4  5
2  6  7  8
```

how do I get the same output using numpy? I tried numpy where but it returns the indices, not the values.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [120]:
x[x[: , 2] > 2]
Out[120]:
array([[ 3.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 6.,  7.,  8.]])
```

### Break it down

---

```
In [122]:
mask = x[: , 2] > 2
mask
Out[122]:
array([False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

In [123]:
x[mask]
Out[123]:
array([[ 3.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 6.,  7.,  8.]])
```

Comment: beautiful - makes lots of intuitive sense too. thanks a lot Nader!